# Is using if statements possible with Tkinter Buttons

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

What I would like to occur is that when I press the other button, the first label is destroyed and only the corresponding label is on the GUI.  Is there a way to incorporate If statements into this or should I approach it another way?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x50")
def func1():
    label = Label(root, text = 'Hello', fg="White", bg="Orange" )
    label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
def func2():
    label = Label(root, text = 'Goodbye', fg="White", bg="Orange" )
    label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

button1 = Button(root, text = "Button 1", command = func1, fg="White", 
bg="Black", width=10, height=5)
button1.pack(side=LEFT)
button2 = Button(root, text = "Button 2", command = func2, fg="White", 
bg="Black", width=10, height=5)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Would probably be easier to have a single Label, created at the start, and have your two buttons just set its text property.

Comment: Commands run by tkinter are no different than any other command in python. Of course they can use `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach that @jasonsharper proposed: It is indeed easier to have a single Label, created at the start, then to use the two buttons to set its text, and other properties.

```
import tkinter as tk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("250x50")

    def set_label(txt):
        label['text'] = txt
        label['fg'] = "White"
        label['bg'] = "Orange"

    button1 = tk.Button(root, text = "Button 1", command = lambda x='hello': set_label(x), fg="White", bg="Black", width=10, height=5)
    button1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    button2 = tk.Button(root, text = "Button 2", command = lambda x='bye': set_label(x), fg="White", bg="Black", width=10, height=5)
    button2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    label = tk.Label(root, text='')
    label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    root.mainloop()
```

#### Note:

Please avoid `import *` --> to keep your namespace clean, use `import tkinter as tk`